# MySQL SUM to PHP While Loop

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am not sure how to get the result of a Mysql SUM into your while loop THEN into a variable for displaying in an HTML table.

Firstly I pass a list of codes ie ("1111", "33311", "43433") to a HTML form textarea then implode those codes into a variable called $in.  I then pass the list of codes (represented by $in) to my SQL Query.

**Mysql Query**

```
SELECT tbl1.code, tbl1.name, tbl1.cost, tble.price, tbl1.vat, sum(tbl2.onhand) as onhand 
FROM tbl1 
INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.code=tbl2.code 
WHERE (tbl2.name='AC' OR tbl2.name='WH') 
AND tbl1.code IN ($in)
```

**NOTE** The query works if I do this instead (without the SUM and brackets) BUT it still shows an empty table cell for $stock:

```
  tbl1.vat, tbl2.onhand AS onhand
```

I am then attempting to pass the value of the Mysql SUM function to a variable, then display that value within a table  with php echo.

**PHP**

```
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $code = $row['code'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $cost = $row['cost'];
        $price = $row['price'];
        $vat = $row['vat'];
        $stock = $row['onhand'];  **Result from the Mysql SUM**


...........}
```

**HTML TABLE**

```
    echo "<td>" . $name . " </td>";
    echo "<td>" . $cost . " </td>";
    echo "<td>" . $price . " </td>";
    echo "<td>" . $vat . " </td>";
    echo "<td>" . $stock . " </td>";
```

The Mysql query does work as I've tested it in Mac Terminal Mysql but when I attempt to replicate that in php, the $stock is not getting echoed to the table cell??

Cheers

Comment: Is the bracket ) a typo? $stock = $row['onhand)'];

Comment: yeah, thanks for highlighting that

Comment: @Hexana So your code does still not work without it?

Comment: No.  The cell for the $stock is empty but all the rest of the data displays ok so I am thinking its the way I'm handling the sum in the $result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your missing a [group by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) in your sql. Maybe changing it to

```
SELECT tbl1.code, tbl1.name, tbl1.cost, tbl1.price, tbl1.vat, sum(tbl2.onhand) as onhand 
FROM tbl1 
INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.code=tbl2.code 
WHERE (tbl2.name='AC' OR tbl2.name='WH') AND tbl1.code IN ($in)
GROUP BY tbl1.code, tbl1.name, tbl1.cost, tbl1.price, tbl1.vat
```

might work.

Also notice how I changed `tble.price` to `tbl1.price` since it looks like a typo

Comment: Omar, I have success at last.  I added GROUP BY and then did <pre> var_dump($row)</pre>  which is returning the onhand value in the mysql.  And now the $stock variable is displaying the onhand :)  Great stuff Omar.  It was GROUP BY that was missing all along.  Well done and thank you.

Answer (score -1):

just wanna point out a fact...
hope you are aware that sum is an aggregate function...so using it without a group by clause will cause it to return a just a single row containing the sum total of all the records

```
SELECT tbl1.code, tbl1.name, tbl1.cost, tbl1.price, tbl1.vat, sum(tbl2.onhand) as onhand 
FROM tbl1 
INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.code=tbl2.code 
WHERE (tbl2.name='AC' OR tbl2.name='WH') AND tbl1.code IN ($in)
GROUP BY tbl1.code, tbl1.name, tbl1.cost, tbl1.price, tbl1.vat
```